# WordPress awesomplete not adding clicked suggestion query string to end of URL on submit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, autocomplete, submit, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want the autocomplete form to be submitted when a user clicks a suggestions from the ul dropdown. At the moment you have to press 'enter' key to submit the form.

I have tried adding the code offered this solution: [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/auto-submit-form-2]:

Go to file `awesomeplete.js`

2/ Search for this code:

```
_.REPLACE = function (text) {
this.input.value = text.value;
```

3/ add this line:

```
$(‘input[type=submit]’).click();
```

I have done this and the form does submit on complete BUT the query string is empty:

```
example.com/?s=
```

It just adds

```
/?s=
```

to the end of the URL when you click the suggestion.

How should I alter the `awesomplete.js` file to populate the URL query string with the suggestion that the user clicks?

Thank you in advance to all those kind enough to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = window.location.origin + '?s=' + text.value;
```

This line of code worked